# How to get Sitecore Explorer to show the Display Name for an item

Tags: sitecore-rocks

Is there an option in Sitecore Rocks that makes Sitecore Explorer show the Display Name for an item instead of using the item name? I've looked through the options/right-click menu but I haven't seen anything. The closest thing I have found is `right click > Tasks > Set Display Names` but that just sets the field and doesn't affect how Sitecore Explorer displays the item.

I'm using Sitecore Rocks version 2.1.86

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer is no.

But you can update the code of [Sitecore Rocks on GitHub](https://github.com/JakobChristensen/Sitecore.Rocks). I have investigated a bit and saw that Sitecore Rocks only uses the item name.

At the namespace `Sitecore.Rocks.ContentTrees.Items.ItemTreeViewItem`, you will see in the constructor that the Text property used to display on the Content Tree Pane is assigned the item name.

Please see screenshot below

[image]

You can change it here. Moreover, I haven't got into deep analysis of the code but from my point of view, this is the start point.